# $location.path does not work in popup browser window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, popup, window

In my JavaScript Addin for Excel, I use `window.open("https://localhost:3000/#/posts/editor/", "popup", "width=1000, height=1100")` to popup a browser window.

I realise that, unlike a normal browser, we can NOT modify manually the URL in this popup browser window.

This page is built by `angularjs`, I have a save button in this page, it is linked to the following function:

```
$scope.save = function () {
    posts.create({ title: "newCreated", link: "" })
        .success(function (post) {
            $location.path("/posts/editor/" + post._id)
        })
})
```

I realise that `$location.path` does NOT redirect the page in this popup window. Whereas, in a normal browser, `$location.path` works.

Does anyone know if it is possible to unlock the popup browser window so that `$location.path` work?

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: try with  $scope.$apply()

Comment: there is no error in console @Keshav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$rootScope.$apply` or `$scope.$apply()`

```
$scope.save = function () {
    posts.create({ title: "newCreated", link: "" })
        .success(function (post) {
           $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            $location.path("/posts/editor/" + post._id)
            console.log($location.path());
          });
        })
})
```

Comment: I tried `$scope.$apply()`, we could see in the url bar, the new address flashes, then it restores to `...posts/editor/`.

Comment: `$rootScope.$apply` gives an `$digest already in progress` error.

Comment: $scope.$apply() try this outside of the method after  the you set path .,,.. you can also use $state as well

Comment: posts/editor is the id present there ?? or is it undefined

Comment: `posts/editor` is the initial state, after `saving`, we expect to go eg, `posts/editor/oA47XgF-m0WQkpYuAAAJ`

Comment: I have not tried `$state.go`, do you think it can replace `$location.path` completely?

Comment: yes .. more you can pass values or even object with it

Comment: Sorry, it is still important for me to see the url changed in the url bar... isn't here no way to unlock to popup browser window?

Comment: could you try window.location

Comment: I tried `$window.location.assign("#/posts/editor/" + post._id)`, we could see in the url bar the new address flashes, then it restores to `.../posts/editor/`. I guess it is still because the url bar is locked...

Comment: is it due to browser based configuration ?

Comment: do post the solution

Comment: I realised that the url `"/posts/editor/" + post._id` can NOT be loaded in a normal browser, because of bugs in my program. I have corrected them, now, it can be loaded in a normal browser as well as the popup window browser by `$location.path`. So `$location.path` works even though the url bar is not editable. Thank you for your answer, it is good to know alternatives like `$state.go` and `window.location`...